# Funneling Proxy Server through AWS Workspaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, workspace, rets, ip-restrictions

I use RETSConnector to diagnose RETS server feeds.  Some are IP restricted.  I am trying to access these feeds through an AWS Windows 7 Workspace.  You can connect with a proxy server, but it doesn't seem to affect the IP the space is reporting.  So my question is, is there anyway I can get AWS Workspace/Windows 7 to reports the proxy server IP internally, thus allowing me to utilize the IP that is already stored in various vendor accounts.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a networking issue, you would need to setup a VPN in one of the whitelisted networks.